# 12VDC Fan rated at 0.08A only drawing 0.04A, can I increase current draw in order to bring the rpm up?

Tags: current, amperage, fan, fault

I've built a small desktop fume extractor for soldering.

It uses a 120mm 1000RPM, 12V, 0.08A case fan. Not huge, but it does the job.

The fan is only drawing roughly 0.04A and I have been fault finding and theory checking all afternoon and I can't figure it out and I feel like such a fool now, I should know this.

The fan is powered by a 12V DC 1.5A supply.

Comment: You can only increase current draw by increasing the voltage and I wouldn't do that.

Comment: In what way do you think there's a fault? Is it not running at around the correct speed?

Comment: Thanks po.pe, that was my only thought out of it so far and as you said, wouldn't be ideal.

Comment: Andy it seems as though its running slower than it should, and given that its drawing half the rated Amps I thought there must be something wrong.

Comment: If you've got the amperage, what does the datasheet say about RPM? Is it a PWM fan?

Comment: 1000rpm on the sheet. It also states that it is simply a DC Fan (to my understanding that rules out PWM..?).

Comment: It is a three wire fan however, I understand the third wire is to monitor RPM, but in this configuration outside if my PC I'm unsure how useful that wire is to me. My plan B is to manage it with my Arduino somehow to measure, and hopefully get an answer.

Comment: Internally the fan is a BLDC motor with a three-phase switching circuit and position sensing. It's not a brushed DC motor. Note that if you are addressing someone in a comment you should ping them by using `@username` (with no spaces). Then your response will show up in their inbox.

Comment: @translator thanks! Ha, I was going to try that!

Comment: measuring amps will not tell you the fan speed,  volts are a better indicator, add some friction to the fan (press on the hub with something) see what the amps do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .08A is most likely just a guide to power consumption, not a spec. The fan is designed to work on 12VDC, and that's what you should give it. The current draw will depend on the load on the fan which usually won't change much. You could try upping the voltage *a bit* but it's really pot luck how far and at some point you will damage it if you go too far.

(Of course if you have a comprehensive data sheet for the fan you might be able to learn the max voltage, but mostly this info doesn't exist on cheaper models.)

If you don't have enough air movement, the solution is a bigger and stronger fan, or multiple fans.

Comment: Absolutely, thanks @danmcb I understand what you're putting across there. 12VDC indeed was exactly what I gave it. All seems to make good sense now.

Comment: thank you, pls mark as answer if this does what you need.

Answer (score 0):

0.08A is probably the MAX power consumption while the fan is spinning at its rated rpm, Not normal power consumption. Fans are used in casings which decrease the airflow and make fans struggle hence they draw more amps, try covering both sides of fan with something like a cardboard or your hands and you will notice increase in Amp draw.

Regarding the rpm, you are probably guessing rpm by the sound fan is making, fans makes louder noise when attached to something because of vibrations and decreased airflow mimicking the effect of higher rpm, Ambient temperature also is a huge factor

Comment: Fabulous, thanks @asim I appreciate it. My understanding was that applying "drag" to the fan would increase consumption, and so it did. Youre spot on with the sound, and air restriction of cases too. Great point. Need to brush up on my HVAC engineering too! Mostly my curiosity was just by eyeballs the fan and noticing it seemed a little slow, but I don't have much to reference 1000rpm to. Will likely invest in something more powerful. Thanks!